# Format Date category axis in chart component

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

How can I format category axes in chart?

I found [this help file](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/CategoryAxisLabels/#toc-dateformats), but I can not connect it with my source code:

```
    <kendo-chart [categoryAxis]="{ categories: graphsCategories }">
        <kendo-chart-legend position="bottom" orientation="horizontal"></kendo-chart-legend>
        <kendo-chart-series>
            <kendo-chart-series-item *ngFor="let item of graphsSeries" type="line" 
                                     [data]="item.timers" 
                                     [name]="item.name">
            </kendo-chart-series-item>
        </kendo-chart-series>
    </kendo-chart>
```

I would like to format date to view only days:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<kendo-chart-series-item *ngFor="let item of graphsSeries" type="line" [data]="item.timers" [name]="item.name">
</kendo-chart-series-item>
```

To this:

```
<kendo-chart-series-item *ngFor="let item of graphsSeries" type="line" [data]="item.timers" [name]="item.name">
        <kendo-chart-category-axis-item-labels format="EEEE">
        </kendo-chart-category-axis-item-labels>
</kendo-chart-series-item>
```

Change the format to whatever you want but `EEEE` will give you the day

Comment: It is not working. Are you sure this should go into the series? I have multiple series, but all share same categorical axis. So shouldn't there be some global setting?

Comment: Yes, i have it in my code. I use the format `dd/MM` but `EEEE` should display the day of the week according to the date